# How to get a container ID from within the container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm making an app that scan the container for viruses, then if the container is infected it kills the container and deploy an older image of said container, presumably without the virus, but to do that I would need the app to know the countainer id of the countainer it's in, but I cant seen to figure that out

Comment: You might try `/etc/hostname` but it's _not_ really reliable.

Comment: it returns permition denied

Comment: echo `$HOSTNAME` will give the hostname. However your question requires more details. How are you starting the container. Why is the container id *not* available at time of creation.

Comment: "it returns permition denied" --- what "it"?

Comment: @GabrielMeirelles you don't have root permissions in the container, when you try to execute in container, you need root privileges. However you don't need to execute anything, parse the `HOSTNAME` environment variable.

Comment: This sounds like you're writing a system-privileged tool, that can read any file from any context on the host, and manipulate arbitrary processes or containers.  I'd expect a tool with that level of privilege to most likely run outside a container (and probably not be runnable at all in Kubernetes).

Comment: I am logged as root, used [docker exec -it -u 0 <container-id> sh], but the container still returns Permission denied when running /etc/hostname, witch is strange
echo $HOSTNAME worked though

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/), so you can use the `proc` file system.

> If you just want the container id and nothing else /proc/self/cgroup should have a line that begins with docker followed by a string that contains the ID.

and it will give something like this

```
/docker/036497b7356b384afd78b529183bee0da5c61bfd378397159e9ff1f9165d0021/kubepods/besteffort/pode6b01d7d-1921-4cc2-b0bb-b0af0e98f51e/c408ed3e894e8706520315230cda7f34dce287223df6a0555b47b0caa979d6e7
```

and

```
c408ed3e894e8706520315230cda7f34dce287223df6a0555b47b0caa979d6e7
#which you can see in the pod too
"containerStatuses": [
            {
                "containerID": "docker://c408ed3e894e8706520315230cda7f34dce287223df6a0555b47b0caa979d6e7",
      }
```

[provide a portable mechanism for processes within container to obtain their image and container ids #1105](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/issues/1105#issuecomment-1002888071)

[how to get the container id in pod? #50309](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50309)